# Detect "Node redraw completed" event after adding node to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a single-page application (SPA) that dynamically shows different parts of DOM by adding and removing DOM subtrees (nodes with their children).

They act like a "pages", switched by the menus and app logic, and may contain a lot of child elements, like controls, text, tables etc.

The problem is, that when the new node added, it takes a long for browser to draw it, and that leads to the flickering. I tried to add a node with the opacity=0 and to change the opacity to 1 then, but how could I understand the timeout required?

Is it possible to detect when redraw is completed, and to make new node visible only after that?

I tried to use MutationObserver but it just calls my callback immediately after node was added, not when it is actually drawn. Now I use "setTimeout" but it is not possible to find out the timeout value to use.

I don't want to make app too laggy, and at the other hand, short timeouts for complex nodes with a lot of children ain't preventing this redraw flickering.

Please help.

Comment: Adding the subtree with opacity 0 will not prevent re-paint. When adding a subtree the browser will re-layout the page. In turn some parts of it _might_ have moved which makes it necessary to in turn repaint them _eventually_. Even if the layout did not change the browser can still not know that nothing has to be re-painted. You should inspect the rendering performance with browser tools to know what takes long. From your description it's not easy to properly help. Actually your question is too broad I think. Consider creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  Sure, it takes some time to redraw, and i want to perform an action after redraw is completed and new sizes are known. The question is, how can my script understand that it is completed and sizes are actual